# Is there a shorcut to comment like this /** */ in Visual Studio code?

Tags: function, visual-studio-code, comments, function-declaration

I know that there is shift + alt + A

But i wonder if there is a shortcut to comment like this:

```
> /** */
```

In order to give a function a describe

like this:

```
>   /**   
>   * Start the camera application and return information about
>   * captured imagefiles.   
>   * @param options   
>   * @returns {Promise<MediaFile[]>}
>   */
```

Comment: If you literally type `/**` don't you get the `*/` completion?

Comment: There's an extension that auto-completes `*/` when you type `/**`: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kevinkyang.auto-comment-blocks

Comment: @AnsonH I think it is built-in now, no need for an extension.  See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20044

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It like @Mark said its autogenerate when you type /**
I was so used to use shift + alt + A that I didn`t realized